# Is there a limit to the number of soft credits you can add to a contribution?

Tags: civicontribute, soft-credit

Is there a limit to the number of soft credits you can add to a contribution? If so, is there a way to change the limit?

Comment: Don't think there are limits. Have you run into any?

Comment: I have to do further testing but someone reported a limit of 10. I will post back after I investigate more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I see that we have a limit for generating soft credit blocks on the New Contribution Page to 10.

I don't think we can modify this limit from the UI level as it is [hardcoded to a value of 10 here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Contribute/Form/SoftCredit.php#L95-L96). Changing this value to 16 can generate 15 softcredit values and so on:)

Modifying here can result in loosing this feature after upgradation to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I also found [this CRM-15802 issue in Jira](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15802) which relates exactly to this discussion and I hope to produce a pull request using Coleman's "cheap trick" idea of using [jquery.clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to produce a form with essentially no limit to soft credits.