# Is there a work around for the limit (10) of soft credits that can be added to a contribution?

Tags: civicontribute, soft-credit

We need a way to work around the limit of soft credits that can be added to a contribution.  I understand the limit is 10 but that is insufficient for our needs.
Please advise.

Comment: Are you saying you want to credit more than 10 contacts for one specific contribution?

Comment: probably a duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8550/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-soft-credits-you-can-add-to-a-contribution?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I am looking to increase the limit of 10 contacts for one specific contribution.

Answer (score 1):

There is technically no limit in the soft credit : it's only a limitation in the public form.

If it's a rare case i would propose to simply add the missing soft credit using the API explorer :

- go to menu Support -> Developer -> API Explorer v3 (or v4 but my screenshot is in v3)
- choose entity `ContributionSoft`, Action `create` and set value for `Contribution`, `Soft Credit Amount` and `Contact ID`
- Then use `Execute` button

Like so :

[image]

Otherwise, you will have to create an extension to somehow overwrite the CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution::$_softCreditItemCount value and it should do the trick :

```
  /**
   * @var int
   *
   * Max row count for soft credits. The value here is +1 the actual number of
   * rows displayed.
   */
  public $_softCreditItemCount = 11;
```